# GraphQL: How do I define input parameters/constraints

Tags: python, django, input, graphql, graphene-python

I am looking for a way to include extra info in the schema so the API consumer knows what is expected. Think along the lines of a max length on a string or something. I expect this to be in the schema since that basically replaces the API documentation, right?

I have found this: https://github.com/confuser/graphql-constraint-directive which appears to be similar to what I want, however I don't need the implementation/enforcement since django does that already. I just want to communicate these constraints on input fields.

I am very new to this all, so is there maybe a concept of graphql I am missing? Or how do I add this kind of information in the schema?

EDIT: Maybe this is not only for documenting, but also to tell the frontend how to render fields and/or be able to do some frontend validation. Basically like an OPTIONS request or something.

Comment: Are there any docs you found useful shifting these constraints over? I'm trying to use Formik, and Graphql Code Generator. But I can't see much more than 'String' on an email field. Seems there's a lot of information that gets lost. Did you have much luck?

Comment: @PortEdison I unfortunately didn't have much luck and gave up on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is to document something about a specific field or type, you can set a `description` on either one. Adding a description doesn't seem to be outlined in the official docs, but there is [this issue](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/660) about it.

```
class MyType(graphene.ObjectType):
    class Meta:
        description = "Some description for MyType"

    my_field = graphene.String(description="Some description for myField")
```

Comment: Ah yeah that's a really good option for documentation! Also know if there's something more strict? Like an OPTIONS request that tells a frontend how to render a form?

Comment: No, at least not anything that's GraphQL-specific. One option might be to implement one or more [custom scalars](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/scalars/#custom-scalars) that would be light wrappers around existing scalars. A client has visibility to the type for a given field through introspection, so they could possibly infer the validation behavior based on the scalar name. For example, you could have a UUID scalar and it would be understood that this should be a properly formatted UUIDv4.

Comment: There actually is a UUID type, BTW -- no need to define one custom https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/graphene/types/uuid.py